# How to drag down columns but change column letter?

Tags: excel, row, autofill

I want to drag down a column but keep the same row of data by going into the next column on another sheet.

For example I have sheet1 with random data in row cells: A1 B1 C1 D1.

On sheet 2 I want to copy this row of data into a column for example: C3 C4 C5 C6.

I have tried used `=OFFSET('sheet1'!$A$1,0,1)` but this just keeps giving the data on cell B1.

How do I drag down the cells (autofill), but change the column letter and keep the same row number from another sheet?

Comment: You can use ROW() (with some adjustment depending on where the formula is located) in place of the "1" in your formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have to transpose() the data as Milind suggested because transpose should keep the formulas "intact" and simply reference the new positions of the cells rather than the old.

The easiest way to do this is to select the entire range of data, right click where you want the new data set to start (C3), then click

1. Paste Special
2. Transpose

Answer (score 5):

Try,

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1, 1, ROW(1:1))
```

Drag down as required. Here it is on a single worksheet.

[image: drag_down_column]

Your formula would have worked as,

```
=OFFSET('sheet1'!$A$1, 0, ROW(1:1)-1)
```

But the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) is volatile¹ and best avoided if possible.

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: Could you explain the arguments a bit more? What does '$1:$1' mean and why is it not equal to '$A$2'? I am just trying to do this for the second row

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Transpose()` function in your target cells i.e. C3,C4,C5,C6.

This [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027) shows the procedure in detail